# use ls command show files sort by copy time?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a remote machine and I `scp`-ed a bunch files from the host.
I want to use `ls` command to show these files, sorted by copied time.
How can I do this?

I tried `ls -lt` but it doesn't seem right. It only shows the file created time, not my copying time.

Comment: *nix does not have a concept of "copy time" or "created time". It stores "change time", "modified time", and "access time". The timestamp you see in ls is the modified time.

Comment: Actually, some unix filesystems do record a file creation time, and GNU `ls` has the `-U` flag to access it.

Comment: @larsks - Thanks for the information. Can you provide an example of a filesystem that supports it?

Comment: Well, `ext4`, for example.  See [this document](http://computer-forensics.sans.org/blog/2011/03/14/digital-forensics-understanding-ext4-part-2-timestamps) and look for `crtime`.

Answer (score 6):

`ls -lt` does not show file creation time...because most Unix filesystems do not actually record the file creation time.  For those that do, it's not necessarily easy to get at it (with `ext4` you can use the `debugfs` command ([doc](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-get-file-creation-time-ext4-ntfs-3g-814130/)), but that's not really germane to your question).

The `-t` flag by default sorts by modification time.  You can use the inode change time (`ctime`) by adding the `-c` flag, so `-lct`.

It's possible that sorting by the inode change time may get you what you want, since this gets updated when the file metadata (size, ownership, permissions) is changed, which will happen when you create a new file.

Comment: The `-U` flag on my GNU ls is "do not sort; list entries in directory order".

Comment: My bad, that was BSD `ls` on my OS X system.

Comment: The question is tagged Linux, but it is still useful information.

Comment: Yeah, just too many windows in front of me :).  I've updated the answer a bit.